Build errors with geolocator package
I'm using the geoloctor package in flutter for android location acquisition, but as soon as I install the package in my flutter project I get an android build error!The error is
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':geolocator_android:compileProfileAidl'.

Here is the relevant configuration for my project：
./android/app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.intelligent_customer_service"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.intelligent_customer_service"
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

./android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

./pubspec.yaml
name: intelligent_customer_service
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.4 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.5.2
  geolocator: ^10.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

There might be a lot of reasons why this error is showing. Did you try to clean your project and build again? You can also try to upgrade the geolocator package to the latest version. Did you also update your gradle.properties file according to the package guide?

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Above is the content of my gradle.properties file
